# How much money do you make for returning craft safely to Kerbin?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

My understanding of KSP 0.24 (First Contract) is returning parts safely to Kerbin will result in profit. My question is, what percent of the part cost is returned? 100%?

Also, if I drop parts, say solid boosters, with chutes will I make the money back if I keep flying or do I need to switch to boosters to get the payment?

Comment: Version 0.24 isn't released yet. Unfortunately [we do not allow questions about unreleased games](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4111/how-should-we-handle-non-beta-pre-release-questions/4111), because answers to them can only be based on speculation or preliminary marketing information which might change until development is complete.

Comment: Now that version 0.24 is released, I nominated this question for reopening.

Comment: @Philipp [See here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6971/). Short version: We don't re-open questions closed for being about Unreleased content just because the content has since been released. This question should not be reopened.

Comment: @BillyMailman We don't, but if questions manage to stick around long enough for them to no longer be unreleased, we serve no one by just deleting it.  I'm surprised 0.24 was released that quickly.

Comment: If you like I can delete the question and re ask the exact same question, to follow these artbitary rules. But isn't the purpose of the rules to get quality content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not.  At best, you receive 100% from surviving resources landing on the launchpad at the Kerbal Space Centre. The percentage will decrease rapidly as you get further away you get, down to a minimum of 10% at the exact opposite of the planet.

As for strapping parachutes to SRB's:

To reduce the amount of calculations the game has to preform, all objects over 2.5km from the active vessel are placed "On Rails"(physics is no longer calculated, object continues on last predicted trajectory). All "On Rails" objects that are too deep into an atmosphere are deleted immediately.

It's also worth noting that only objects attached to a command pod or a probe body will be recovered, the cheapest probe body in the game is three times more expensive than an SRB and you don't get much back from an SRB, because most of it's cost is in fuel.

There are techniques that would allow you to over come these problems, but the extra effort and costs required to achieve them are more than you recover from it.

Comment: You get 100% back when you land exactly on the launch pad or the runway. You can test this easily by creating a new vehicle and recovering it immediately before launch.

Comment: @Philipp - that is likely because you have not used any fuel

Comment: @HorusKol Sure, fuel also costs a few Funds, and any burned fuel is of course irretrievably lost. But you can try with a simple jetplane: When you manage to fly a tour around the space center, land it on the runway and recover it, you get 100% back on all the parts.